# How to autoincrement string in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, while-loop, auto-increment

I want to make field joCode in my program automatically increment, but i have a format like this --> JP100000 , everytime user click button "save", it will increment to JP100001 , JP100002, until JP199999 ..

this is my code :

```
   try {
        int div = view.getCbDiv().getSelectedIndex();
        int l = 100000;
        do {
            if ( div == 0 ) {
                view.getTxtJobCode().setText("JP" + l);
            }
            else {
                view.getTxtJobCode().setText("JU" + l);
            }
        } while(l <= 199999);

        l++;
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to move the `l++` into the `do` block.

Answer (score 2):

Hope your code is written in actionEvent method. So keep your increment counter as global variable

```
private int l = 10000;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int div = view.getCbDiv().getSelectedIndex();
    if (div == 0) {
        view.getTxtJobCode().setText("JP" + l);
    } else {
        view.getTxtJobCode().setText("JU" + l);
    }
    l++;
}
```

Comment: I think the `l++` should be outside of the `else` block, otherwise it won't increment for all cases...

Comment: I am interested in good answers for every (good) question. So there you go. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `NumberFormat` like they show in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html). Maybe something like this:

```
NumberFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("000000");
view.getTxtJobCode().setText("JP" + myFormat.format(l));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andre said, move the `l++` line into your `do` block enclosure:

```
   try {
        int div = view.getCbDiv().getSelectedIndex();
        int l = 100000;
        do {
            if ( div == 0 ) {
                view.getTxtJobCode().setText("JP" + l);
            }
            else {
                view.getTxtJobCode().setText("JU" + l);
            }
            l++;
        } while(l <= 199999);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my example, based on your ID format `JP100001`, length of ID will be **8** and prefix will be **JP** and **JU**.

```
    /**
     * This method is used to format plain id (plain number). Mostly,
     * this method is used in setId() methods of entities.
     * <p>
     * E.g.
     * Input: id=523, prefix="JP", maxLength=15
     * Output: JP0000000000523
     * <p>
     * @param id id must not be null.
     * @param prefix prefix must not be null.
     * @param maxLength maximum length of the id string and it must not be negative number.
     * @return a formatted id string
     */
    public static String formatId(String id, String prefix, int maxLength) {
        if (!id.startsWith(prefix)) {
            int length = id.length() + prefix.length();
            for (; (maxLength - length) > 0; length++) {
                id = '0' + id;
            }
            id = prefix + id;
        }
        return id;
    }

    yourMethod() {
        try {
            int div = view.getCbDiv().getSelectedIndex();
            int l = 100000;
            do {
                if ( div == 0 ) {
                    view.getTxtJobCode().setText(formatId((l + ""), "JP, 8));
                }
                else {
                    view.getTxtJobCode().setText(formatId((l + ""), "JU, 8));
                }
            } while(l <= 199999);

            l++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ayyoung, It is id generation. You can configure ID format and length as you wish.

Comment: it can't work , because formatId (String, String, int) but when its call in setText , it's required (int,String,int) ...

Comment: @ayyoung :) try again with `(l + "")` `int` to `string`, I will update my post.

Comment: the value show the lastes value, but i want to make this looping, loop the value when i insert new data, not display all the looping value at the same time, one by one when i click button new once, it will display JP/JU100001, when i click new again it will display JP/JU100002, and so on ..